# Middleware Email duplicate controls bad code modeling

Tags: node.js, express, routes, middleware

I need to add a node.js express middleware for Emails duplicates controls, and a short and easy looking code.

This is my **middleware.js** file :

```
// -----------------------------------      MIDDLEWARE FUNCTIONS -------------------------------------------
module.exports = {
    /*
     * CHECKING FOR DUPLICATE EMAIL 
     * @params 
     * @return NEXT()
     * @error  Status 403s
     */
    async duplicate_email(db, req, res, next) {
        let availableEmail = await db.collection("users").findOne({ 'email': req.body.email })
        if (!availableEmail) {
            console.log(" FORBIDDEN  ")
            res.status(403).send({ errorCode: "403" })
            return
        } else {
            next() // continue the process
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Register web service, in another file called **usersCrud.js** , I'm struggling since 3 days to make it work but no way :

```
/*
* Register anonymous user
* @params JSON OBJECT : {}
* @return 200
* @error  400
*/
app.post("/registerUser", middleware.duplicate_email(), function(req, res) {

    try {
        var user = new User({
            _id: null,
            prenom: req.body.prenom,
            nom: req.body.nom,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10),
            role: "user",
            permissions: middleware.create_permissions("user"),
            filenames: [],
            groups: [],
            last_update: new Date(),
            img: "",
            birthday: "",
            age: "",
            job: "",
            mentra: "",
        });
        db.collection("users").insertOne(user);
        console.log("Added one user");
        res.sendStatus(200);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(400);
    }

});
```

This is the error :

```
Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Promise]
```

I have tried tons of things, like adding the db parameter, use a return function, removing all parameters, but I can' t make it work. The code would be really simplier if that thing could work like this, but I don't know if it is possible.
Maybe it is easy to solve for you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you what's wrong, since you invoke `middleware.duplicate_email()` in your `app.post` and thus returns a promise. You need to pass the function without invoking it or define it as a factory function that returns the middleware and takes the `db` object as a parameter. I'd go with the second approach, which would look something like:

```
module.exports = {    
    duplicate_email(db) {
        return async (req, res, next) => {
            let availableEmail = await db.collection("users").findOne({'email': req.body.email})
            if (!availableEmail) {
                console.log(" FORBIDDEN  ")
                res.status(403).send({errorCode: "403"})
                return
            } else {
                next() // continue the process
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
app.post("/registerUser", middleware.duplicate_email(db), function(req, res) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot EOL ! I'm trying out your solution now , what would I do without major devs helps like you, I wish I could pay for that

Comment: Works perfectly , sometimes I pay on paypal if u have one , cause it deserves it. Stackoverflow is missing ' pay for help ' button under each answers

Comment: It's fine, happy to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do something like this?

```js
app.post("/registerUser", await middleware.duplicate_email(), function(req, res)
```

It has to be included in the `async` function of course to be able to use the `await` keyword. As the error says, the callback is expected, but you provided a not resolved `Promise`.
Another thing that may work is:

```js
app.post("/registerUser", async () => { 
    const result = await middleware.duplicate_email(); 
    return result;
}, function(req, res) {
   // stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Elszczepano ! I'm trying out this now !